# How to assert exception type and exception message?

Tags: c#, xunit

This is my test method in XUnit.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task AddCampaign_ReturnBadRequestWhenDateIsInvalid()
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();
        string title = string.Format("Test Add Campaign {0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        var campaignAddDto = new CampaignDTORequest
        {
            Title = title
        };
        var encodedContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(campaignAddDto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Campaign/add", encodedContent);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignDTOResponse>(responseString);

        Assert.False(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(()=> client.PostAsync("/api/Campaign/add", encodedContent));
    }
```

The first assert is works. I am stuck with second assert. How do I assert both exception type (ArgumentNullException) and its exception message?

This is the service method

```
    public async Task<Campaign> AddCampaignAsync(Campaign campaign)
    {            
        if (campaign.StartDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Start Date cannot be null or empty.");
        }
        
        await _context.Campaigns.AddAsync(campaign);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return campaign;
    }
```

Updated after the clue from Lei Yang.

```
var exceptionDetails = Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => client.PostAsync("/api/Campaign/add", encodedContent));
Assert.Equal("Start Date cannot be null or empty.", exceptionDetails.Result.Message);
```

But still doesn't work.

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
> (Assert.Throws() Failure
> Expected: typeof(System.ArgumentNullException)
> Actual:   (No exception was thrown))

Tried the solution from Dai but still got error.

> ```
> Assert.Throws() Failure
> Expected: typeof(System.ArgumentNullException)
> Actual:   (No exception was thrown)
> ```

This is my API method.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<CampaignDTOResponse>> AddCampaign([FromBody] CampaignDTORequest newCampaign)
    {
        try
        {
            var campaign = _mapper.Map<Campaign>(newCampaign);
            campaign = await _campaignService.AddCampaignAsync(campaign);
            var campaignDtoResponse = _mapper.Map<CampaignDTOResponse>(campaign);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCampaignById), new { id = campaignDtoResponse.Id }, campaignDtoResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(0, ex, ex.Message);
            return Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Updated: I move the checking from service to api.

```
if (newCampaign.StartDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
{
    return BadRequest("Start Date cannot be null or empty.");
}
```

and I assert them like below.

```
Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
Assert.Equal("Start Date cannot be null or empty.", responseString);
```

Comment: `Assert.Throws` has a return type

Comment: @LeiYang I updated my answer. But still doesn't work.

Comment: ^^ it returns the exception instance on which you then can assert its message. Btw: I personally fell in love with "FluentAssertions" lib. It makes coming up with that kind of asserts really tester friendly. (Not affiliated)

Comment: @Steve You need to `await` it.

Comment: @Fildor `Shouldly` is better :)

Comment: @Dai Will not argue about that. I think we can agree that any of those is better than the vanilla assertions of xUnit?

Comment: @Fildor oh, indubitably! `Assert.ShouldlyOrFluentAssertionsIsBetterThanXUnitAssert()` :)

Comment: Okay, will try `Shouldy` and `FluentAssertions` next time. Now just want to get this Xunit version to work first.

Comment: @Steve That sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Steve The API method makes this kind of x-y. The method doesn't throw anything. So even if your assertions were 100% correct, they would fail, because your testee does not behave as you expect it to.

Comment: ^^ So you have two options: Assert the actual behavior or refactor the method to behave as expected. I'd consider the arguments in @Dai's answer, though.

Comment: @Fildor, not really understand Dai's answer lol. Which means if my argument is null, it should just return bad request and not argumentnullexception?

Comment: @Steve Your code is throwing `ArgumentNullException` when `campaign` is **not `null`** (otherwise it cannot dereference `StartDate.Equals`) - that's just flat-out _wrong_. Please read-up on how to correctly represent and enforce preconditions.

Comment: @Fildor , I updated my answer. I move the null checking at api layer and updated my test and it works now.

Comment: @Steve What do you mean by "api layer"? "API" is a very vague term thanks to everyone abusing when they should be using the term _web service_. \*sigh\*

Comment: I think from my understand after what you guys said, Web api doesn't throw exception but only error like bad request or internal server error. In my case, should be bad request. But if I test the service directly (without going thru Web Api), then I can use Assert.Throw to check the exception type. Is my understand correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Assert.ThrowsAsync` is still an `async Task` method](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/58a59628853ed7a63895945fdac7984a92da2343/ExceptionAsserts.cs), so you need to `await`  that to ensure the task continuation (that does the actual assert) can run correctly:

```
[Fact]
public async Task AddCampaign_Return_bad_request_when_date_is_invalid()
{
    [...]

    Assert.False(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(()=> client.PostAsync("/api/Campaign/add", encodedContent));
}
```

---

### However...

- ....please reconsider your design: **[Exceptions should be exceptional](https://mattwarren.org/2016/12/20/Why-Exceptions-should-be-Exceptional/)**.

  - Though *not everyone* agrees: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184654/ive-been-told-that-exceptions-should-only-be-used-in-exceptional-cases-how-do
  - Though as Java has checked-exceptions, it can make sense to use exceptions to represent all kinds of error-conditions instead of just *exceptional* error conditions - whereas C#/.NET does not have checked-exceptions and so requires people to read hand-written documentation to see what the declared exceptions are, if any - which makes *proper* error-handling in .NET rather painful unless you agree to throw only in exceptional conditions and instead use return-types to represent non-exceptional error conditions.
- Even if you want to throw, you should not be throwing `ArgumentNullException` to represent HTTP 400 Bad Request responses.

  - The `ArgumentException` class and its subclasses (`ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, etc) should only be used to indicate [a failed precondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) - not a failed postcondition nor internal error (use `InvalidOperationException` for that).
  - Personally I don't think that web-service clients should *ever* throw exceptions for any response unless it's *actually* an "*exceptional*" response or situation.
  - If you use NSwag to generate web-service clients then it will generate `ApiException<TResponse>` for you, which is far more useful.
  - Though my preference is to return a discriminated-union of all *reasonable* possible responses (namely, whatever is declared by `[ProducesResponseType]`).

Comment: I'd suggest to add the part where you assign the return to a var and assert the message, just to completely answer the question?

Comment: @Fildor Better idea: the OP should not be using `ArgumentNullException` for this - and we should not be testing `Exception.Message` because it's localizable. Furthermore, non-exceptional situations should not be represented by exceptions.

Comment: While I agree with your comment, the question was _how to do it_. So if another SO user is to look for it (maybe for a better reason), they shall find a useful answer to _that_ , don't they?

Comment: I tried but still got errror. I have added my api method. Is it because of my try catch return ` return Problem(ex.Message);`?

Comment: @Steve How do you expect the method to throw anything, if you catch any exception it _could_ throw?

Comment: @Steve `Assert.Throws` can only assert an **uncaught exception**. `Assert.Throws` does not verify an exception was thrown-and-caught. For that you need to hook into `AppDomain`, which you should not do in tests like these.

Comment: What is failed pre condition and post condition?

Comment: @Steve http://www.cs.albany.edu/~sdc/CSI310/MainSavage/notes01.pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition

Answer (score 4):

You can capture an exception with `Record.Exception` and assert it:

```cs
// Act
Action action = async () => await client.PostAsync("/api/Campaign/add", encodedContent);
var ex = Record.Exception(action);

// Assert
Assert.NotNull(ex);
Assert.IsType<ArgumentNullException>(ex);
```

Comment: Not sure if the second snippet is correct regarding `async` ?

Comment: @mohsen, I tried your code (the second one), but still doesn't work.  Assert.IsType() Failure. Expected: System.ArgumentNullException. Actual:   (null)

Comment: I wanted to make up for the down. Forgetting an "await" ... you can drop a comment or simply edit it in. A downvote without comment is just unfair in that case.

Comment: @Steve If you did not reove the try/catch, your method still does not throw anything :D

Comment: Wondering how `Assert.NotNull` passed but `Assert.IsType()` threw `System.ArgumentNullException. Actual: (null)`? @Steve

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour His API Method doesn't actually throw any exception.